# Are they Cassinian Ovals?

Tags: geometry, plane-curves

Are these 'Cassinian Ovals' known? Has any physical meaning been found?

For the curves sketched below the foci are at $(2,1),(-2,-3)$ and squared product distances are $ (1.4^2,1.7^2 , 2^2)$. Thanks for the attention you have always given.

[image]